# How to login using Windows Authentication in .NET Core with Servicestack

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack, windows-authentication

In previous applications using ServiceStack, me and my team have been using .NET Framework and the included AspNetWindowsAuthProvider.

Having switched to .NET Core we have discovered that the included provider is no longer in ServiceStack.Core.

How can I use Windows Authentication in a ServiceStack.Core application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack doesn't have a built-in Windows Auth Provider for .NET Core, a potential solution is to use [ASP.NET Core's Identity Auth with ServiceStack](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-identity-aspnet), a pre-configured solution is available from the [mvcidentity](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentity) .NET Core Project Template.

Then [Configure Windows Authentication in the ASP.NET Core App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) which is used by the [NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-identity-aspnet#propagating-extended-user-info) to create an Authenticated ServiceStack Session from the Authenticated ASP.NET Core Identity.

Comment: Having started with your empty web application project template. What is absolutely necessary to make this work in an existing project?

Comment: @glazjoon Start with the linked [mvcidentity](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentity) instead which contains a pre-configured working template.

Comment: Yea, that's a great tip. Sadly we are too far gone into the project. Thanks. Maybe we have to migrate the code.